# Can subjects be used as objects?

Tags: to-infinitive, transitivity

- This robot is designed to play with. (The robot is designed for being played, so I can play with the robot.)
- This water is too hot to drink. (The water is too hot, so I cannot drink the water.)

“Play with” and “drink” are transitive verbs. Can subjects be used as objects in this case?

Comment: Your question concerns two completely different subjects. Please edit your question to remove one subject, and create a separate question for it. Please also add more explanation for each question- I don't understand what you want to know, or why.

Comment: Yes. In your second example, "This water is too hot to drink __ ]", the gap __ is object of "drink" and is anaphoric to the subject, "this water".  Your first example won't work; you need "to be played  with __ ", where the gap __ is object of the prep "with" and is anaphoric to the subject, "this robot".

Comment: Offhand, I'm not sure why the two examples are different. But so far as I'm concerned, #1 is invalid - it should be the passive construction *This robot is designed **to be played** with*. But #2 is perfectly natural. Even though *This water is too hot **to be drunk*** might seem more "consistent / logical" (and it's certainly *valid*), that passivized version sounds decidedly weird.

Comment: ...but I note that *This robot is **too dangerous** to play with* sounds okay to me (and *...too dangerous to be played with* sounds "stilted"). But *This water is **intended** to drink* is completely unacceptable (must be *...intended to be drunk*).

Comment: related: [“interesting to be watched” versus “interesting to watch”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58652/interesting-to-be-watched-versus-interesting-to-watch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To do or To be done](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267768/to-do-or-to-be-done). Which contrasts, for example, *This is easy **to do*** and *This is easy **to be done***.

Comment: @FumbleFungers I don’t understand because you said 1 is invalid, but according to “interesting to watch” “designed to play with” is valid.

Comment: @user0203 Why have you deleted the sentence "This water is too hot to drink" in your question. You should not make such changes after someone has answered or commented on your question.  And you've now introduced another topic which you were told not to do.

Comment: @BillJ I deleted it because JavaLatte said I shouldn’t question two completely different subjects.

Comment: @user0203 But you shouldn't delete a subject that has already been discussed in comments. You should have deleted the question about "too".

Comment: @BillJ I thought a comment is just a comment, not an answer, sorry.

Comment: To be clear about "This water is too hot to drink ___", it is **gap** that is object of "drink". The interpretation of 'gap' is determined by an antecedent noun phrase, in this case "this water".

Comment: @BillJ I guess only adjectives can have gaps, not participles like “designed.”

Comment: Gap is normally direct object or object of a preposition, but not an adjective.

Comment: @BillJ I mean adjective+”to”+transitive verb, not participle+”to”+transitive verb.

Comment: What do you mean by "participle+”to”+transitive verb"? An example, please.

Comment: @BillJ Gloves are ‘made to wear.’

Comment: Where did you find that example?

Comment: @BillJ In my head hahaha

Comment: Do you think that "wear" has a gap interpreted as "gloves"? Note that your question has been closed as a duplicate.